# Blender 2.8 Image on object

Tags: mesh, image

How can i remove it, since i'm trying transparent eyes and there is an image that's in the way. Im not sure if its an image map though.

i think that's maybe also why my blender is so slow even with so little i work with.

i just followed a tutorial and there you could choose an environment for lightning, but im not sure if that's it and if so, i did delete the environment lighting but its still on the object.

Is there a way to fix it fast?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your mix factor for your gloss is all way to the gloss - try turning that up some and seeing if it gets less of a reflection then.

Answer (score 2):

You're in *LookDev* view, which applies some preset environment maps by default. To view your material as it will appear in your scene, switch to *Render* view, e.g. via the buttons in the 3D view header:

[image]

Comment: I should call you gandals the white :) thanks for the fast help ^^